# Load new html into CefSharp browser while preserving scroll position

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I have a CefSharp browser in a WPF project. It is displaying html that is mostly entered by the user. When the html changes, I need to reload the browser, which I am doing as follows:

```
private void UpdateHTML(ChromiumWebBrowser browser) {
  string outputHTML = this.PrepareHTMLFromUserInput(); 
  string url = @"file:///" + this.GetResourcePath();
  browser.LoadHtml(outputHTML, url);
}
```

That works just fine, but it always scrolls the browser to the top. I want to preserve the y offset. How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of `CefSharp` are you using? I have never heard about a `LoadHtml` method for `ChromiumWebBrowser`...

Comment: `LoadHtml` is an extension method, under the hood it registers a `IResourceHandler`. You can execute some javascript to scroll the window, or include anchor tag in your `url`, use some javascript to determine which tag you need to append. Or choose a different approach and use some javascript to populate the existing form. (or change your calls to ajax ones).

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:** Wrapping the browser in a UserControl, which in turn is inside a ScrollViewer allows one to preserve the y offset. But now I have a new problem -- I need to adjust the height of the ScrollViewer and UserControl to keep up with changes the browser height.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1">
  <UserControl x:Name="WrappingUserControl" Height="2000">
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="EditorBrowser" Address="about:blank"/>
  </UserControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You'd potentially have to send `Mouse Wheel` events to the browser to make this work seemlessly. I'd say it's more effort than it's worth. There's no way to directly get rendered window size, you have to execute javascript (see `FAQ`).

Answer (score 0):

One suboptimal solution could be writing to a file, load it once and then call Reload:

```
browser.Load("c:\....mypath.html");
...
File.AppendText("<p>my html</p>");
...
browser.Reload();
```

It will keep the scrolling position where the user left it.